# How to connect two p2p nodes by ip - altcoin project

Tags: networking, p2p, bitcoin, peer

I made a litecoin clone for experiments & learning. I have compiled and started the headless client (mycoind) at two different (ubuntu) machines:
1. My home machine, with ip1
2. My workplace machine with ip2
I have a VPN connection, so I work on machine 2 using ssh.
In each of the mycoin.conf files I have added the lines "connect=ip", where ip=ip for the other machine. I also do the same with "rpcallowip=ip" (not sure if the last part is needed though)

But the debug.log files only goes like this:

> 2014-05-18 11:45:03 trying connection xx.xx.xx.xx lastseen=0.0hrs
>   2014-05-18 11:45:03 connect() failed after select(): Connection
>   refused

If I start the client without specify connect, it get many connections (I use litecoin ports, so it must be the litecoin network), it seems to be happily mining, not bothering that it is mining coins on its own different chain.
I wonder if it is the ip that is the problem, or if its the firewall - and if there are separate methods to check such connections

Comment: You should probably put this on the bitcoin exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting IPs for rpc and "connect" are just for rpc control and ensuring another ip is being listened to for transactions and block confirmations on the network.

P2P IP connections were in the original bitcoin client but have been disabled and I think completely taken out of the current code base.

An alternative solution would be to use Micropayment Channels over any P2P networking framework... WebRTC DataChannels would make a great candidate for this if you trust the connection server or create a trust mechanism.

Micropayment Channels:

- https://bitcoinj.github.io/working-with-micropayments
- https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-guide#micropayment-channel